# How to multiply a column rowwise to a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array A with dimension (30000, 3, 3)
I have a numpy array B with dimension (30000,)
I want to multiply each scalar in B to the corresponding 3x3 matrix in A, and I want to get the resulting matrix of shape (30000, 3, 3)

I tried using np.multiply function without success.

Comment: You have to align the axes with size 30000 such that A and B broadcast, for instance via: `out = A * B[:, None, None]`. Take a look at the numpy docs on broadcasting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: What was the error?  Something about broadcasting (30000,3,3) with (30000,)?  `B` needs to be (30000,1,1) to properly line up the large 30000 dimension.  `broadcasting` can add leading size 1 dimensions, trailing ones have to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.5, two new operators, `@` and `@=`, were introduced to handle matrix multiplication. These operators were added to address the confusion that arose from using the `*` operator for both element-wise multiplication and matrix multiplication, depending on the specific library or code convention.

The new binary operator `@` is used similarly to `*` but specifically for matrix multiplication. It clarifies that the intention is to perform matrix multiplication rather than element-wise multiplication.

Similarly, the in-place version `@=` can be used for in-place matrix multiplication, similar to `*=` for element-wise multiplication.

```bash
import numpy as np

# Define two matrices A and B
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
B = np.array([[11, 12], [13, 14]])

# Matrix multiplication using @ operator
result_matrix = A @ B
print(result_matrix)
```

For more information, you can refer to [PEP0465](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/), which explains the rationale behind introducing these new operators.

Comment: I think he wants elementwise multiplication, `*`, not matrix multiplication.  `@` has been around for many versions.  It's just `@=` that's new, and not relevant for this mix of shapes